# ServiceStack.Text: How to map type name without having to map all properties?

Tags: servicestack

The __type field generated by ServiceStack for a collection of objects implementing an interface can be verbose.  I am looking to programmatically map the __type value to another value during serialization and back to the proper concrete type value on de-serialization.

I am aware of JsonObject but I do not want to have to code the entire object graph, I just want to be able to override the type name serialization/de-serialization.

I tried JsConfig<Type>.SerializeFn but that code does not get called.